# Selected cropped area not used when cropping some images in TYPO3 backend on the server

Tags: crop, image-manipulation, typo3-11.x

Problem:
In a TYPO3 v11.5.33 project on the server, when I manually crop some images from the TYPO3 backend, the selected cropped area is not used/respected after I save the Content Element record this image is attached to.

For some other images, after cropping, the resulting image is just a black image.

For some other images, especially smaller images, the cropping works well.

I have setup this project on my local PC, but this problem does not occur there. Cropping of all pictures works fine.

ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick are installed on the server. I have tried using both, but I still get the problem.

I will be very glad if anyone could help me with any tipps on what may be issue here.

Thanks.

Comment: have you inspected the usual suspects? enough memory, write permission on the temporarily folders.